# Trying to make a letter guessing game's onkeyup function only accept alphabet keys with the indexOf method

Tags: javascript

Trying to make onkeyup function only accept alphabet keys. (IndexOf is commented out)(I'm using the array already made for all alphabet keys)

I currently have an indexOf commented out

```
var computerChoices = ["q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m"];
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var guessesleft = 9;
var storeduserguess = []

var winsText = document.getElementById("wins-text");
var lossesText = document.getElementById("losses-text");
var guessesleftText = document.getElementById("guessesleft-text");
var userguessesText = document.getElementById("usersguesses-text");
var computerGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
// I couldn't figure out how to make the onkeyup function only accept alphabet keys (still trying(stackoverflow))
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
    // if (computerChoices.indexOf(event) >= 0) {
        console.log(event)
        var userGuess = event.key;
        storeduserguess.push(userGuess);
        if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
            computerGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
            wins++;
            guessesleft = 9;
            storeduserguess = [];
        }
        else if (userGuess !== computerGuess) {
            guessesleft--;
        }
        if (guessesleft === 0) {
            computerGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
            losses++;
            guessesleft = 9;
            storeduserguess = [];
        }
        winsText.textContent = "Wins: " + wins;
        lossesText.textContent = "Losses: " + losses;
        guessesleftText.textContent = "Guesses left: " + guessesleft;
        userguessesText.textContent = "You guessed: " + storeduserguess;
        // open up the console if you want to be a cheater...
        console.log(computerGuess);
        console.log(userGuess)
    // };
};
```

everything else works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "onkeyup" to "onkeypress"

And add this code at the top of the body of the function. Let me know if there's any issues.

```
if(computerChoices.indexOf(event.key) === -1) {
  return event.preventDefault();
}
```